# Terme technique pour « mixing / roller for gas cylinders » ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, terminologie

[image]

« [*Mixing / Roller for gas cylinders*](https://www.lronning.com/products/mixing-roller-for-gas-cylinders-m264-000-xxx) » (©Copyright 1980-2022 L. RÖNNING AB)

L'appareil prend les bouteilles à la verticale, bascule à l'horizontale et des roues font tourner les bouteilles sur elles-mêmes...

Comment désigne-t-on précisément cet objet en français (on étaiera sa réponse et on prendra soin de valider la cohérence du choix de la préposition si c'est le cas) ?

Comment: Qu'est-ce-qu'il y a dans le dictionnaire, Wikipédia, etc ?  What have you found in your research in the dictionary or online, and how did it fall short?  Please take a moment to see the [help] et bienvenue sur French Language Stack Exchange.

Comment: Je ne vois pas de terme spécifique pour ce matériel. On pourra dire *charriot/palette/support pour bouteilles/bonbonnes de gaz".

Comment: (On demandera poliment aux gentils contributeurs d'apporter une réponse)

Comment: @Graffito Il ne s'agit pas de ranger les bouteilles, c'est un appareil qui a une fonction. Il ne faut pas confondre avec des appareils/plateformes sur roues servant à déplacer des marchandises.

Comment: @ʁəʄɘləmɘlə : Bonne remarque, je n'avais pas trop fait attention à la fonction de rotation de l'appareil, ce qui me fait penser aux *gyropalettes* utilisées dans les caves pour le remuage du champagne.

Answer (score 2):

Ce n'est pas suffisamment courant pour que l'expression soit répandue mais s'il fallait lui trouver un nom, ce serait peut-être *mélangeur industriel pour bouteilles de gaz* ou *mélangeur basculant à rouleaux pour bouteilles de gaz*. Ce ne sont pas exactement des rouleaux ici mais c'est ce qui y ressemble le plus:

[image]

https://www.mga-technologies.fr/melangeur-rouleaux-laboratoire/

Comment: Le labo/médical/pharmaceutique permet des analogies. Ils ont _agitateur à_ (qui ne convient pas vu le produit de la question) même si parfois leurs agitateurs roulent. L'_homogénéisateur_, un terme du site de RONNING est aussi utile pour le résultat de l'opération mais décrit peu l'appareil de manière usuelle. La question est difficile. Peut-être que quelqu'un de l'industrie ou un ingénieur francophone dispose d'un terme technique formel, qui sait. Je n'ai pas trouvé hormis d'élaborer similairement à ta réponse.